# How to localize Input File in HTML (Aurelia)?

Tags: html, file, input, localization, aurelia

I want to translate the text in input file through HTML (Aurelia). Here is the code:

```
<input type='file' id="choose-firmware-file" files.bind="selectedFirmwareFile"><br>
```

and the related image you can see here:
[image]

How to translate "Choose File" and "No file chosen" through HTML (Aurelia)??

Answer (score 2):

okay, its no aurelia component, and an HTML Element, i think you need it:

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display:none;"/>

<label for="fileInput">Clique to file(This text needed change when file change event dispatch)</label>
```

I hope help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. you are right, it is HTML element